# React state needed for simple modal form?

Tags: reactjs

So im working on a React app, it's basically a CRUD app pretty much (serving right now as a learning practice project).

Anyways, I have a modal that appears when the user needs to edit some basic information on a resource (right now it's just a "name" that's being edited). The modal is a presentational/dumb component that takes in props from it's parent (Which is essentially just a table of the resources/items).

If im literally only going to be submitting the form to change 1 field I would only need a state with 1 item (for that input field to edit).......does it make sense to STILL make it a class just because it has a state? From what i've read if you have a state you should automatically make it a class?

Is this always true?

Comment: You could use a [hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html).

Comment: @msmith1114 that's fine you can pass form data to function component to edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you talking like this?

When you click on any list item it goes to child(functional) component as you were asking.

You can check working live example [Live demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/excercise-of-hooks-f3jdb)

```
export default function App() {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState(["One", "Two", "Three"]);
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const handleChange = e => {
    setName(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setArr([...arr, name]);
    setName("");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {arr.map(a => (
        <div style={myStyle} key={a}>
          {a} <button onClick={() => setName(a)}>Edit</button>
        </div>
      ))}
      <Child
        handleChange={handleChange}
        handleSubmit={handleSubmit}
        name={name}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
const Child = ({ handleChange, name, handleSubmit }) => {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </form>
  );
};
const myStyle = {
  margin: 5,
  cursor: "pointer",
  border: "1px solid lightgrey",
  padding: "5px",
  display: "flex",
  justifyContent: "space-between"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes whenever you use a state you should make it a class (way back then) but now we have this thing called [HOOKS](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html) that allows you to use states within functional components.

Simple sample implementation below.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Example = () => {
  //creates a state name and a setter for it. Then initialize it with empty string
  const [name, setName] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      //suppose you have input here
      <button onClick={() => setName("Your name value")}>
        Click me
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is clean and nice. Then I can just use the onSubmit to do a callback to a function passed as a prop to send those values to the parent i presume.

Comment: One question: How would I update the setter with my forms input "value's"?